# C# Regex matching

Tags: c#, regex, space

I need to replace some text in C# using RegEx:

```
string strSText = "<P>Bulleted list</P><UL><P><LI>Bullet 1</LI><P></P><P>
<LI>Bullet 2</LI><P></P><P><LI>Bullet 3</LI><P></UL>"
```

Basically I need to get rid of the

```
"<P>"
```

tag(s) introduced between

```
"<UL><P><LI>", 
"</LI><P></P><P><LI>" and
"</LI><P></UL>"
```

I also need to ignore any spaces between these tags when performing the removal.

So

```
"</LI><P></P><P><LI>", "</LI>    <P></P><P><LI>", "</LI><P></P><P>   <LI>" or 
"</LI> <P> </P> <P> <LI>"
```

must all be replaced with

```
"</LI><LI>"
```

I tried using the following RegEx match for this purpose:

```
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "<UL>.*<LI>", "<UL><LI>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "</LI>.*<LI>", "</LI><LI>", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "</LI>.*</UL>", "</LI></UL>", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it performs a "greedy" match and results in:

```
"<P>Bulleted list</P><UL><LI>Bullet 3</LI></UL>"
```

I then tried using "lazy" match:

```
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "<UL>.*?<LI>", "<UL><LI>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "</LI>.*?<LI>", "</LI><LI>", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, "</LI>.*?</UL>", "</LI></UL>", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and this results in:

```
"<P>Bulleted list</P><UL><LI>Bullet 1</LI></UL>"
```

But I want the following result, which preserves all other data:

```
"<P>Bulleted list</P><UL><LI>Bullet 1</LI><LI>Bullet 2</LI><LI>Bullet 3</LI></UL>"
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML.  [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: Would something like `strSText.Replace("<UL><P><LI>", "<UL><LI>");` etc... work?

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp matches one or more `<P>` or `</P>` tags:

```
(?:</?P>\s*)+
```

So if you place that between the other tags you have, you can get rid of them, i.e.

```
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, @"<UL>\s*(?:</?P>\s*)+<LI>", "<UL><LI>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, @"</LI>\s*(?:</?P>\s*)+<LI>", "</LI><LI>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strSText = Regex.Replace(strSText, @"</LI>\s*(?:</?P>\s*)+</UL>", "</LI></UL>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but more of a comment to Jonathon: Parse HTML with [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)